# App Icon Sizes in Xcode's Assets Catalog

Tags: ios, image, resize, icons, retina-display

Is the 29pt for the iPhone already in Retina display? Meaning would I have to put 29pt or 58pt? For the iPad is the 29pt referring to the non-retina/1x or the retina/2x?
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`pt` is points. In 1x that is pixels. In 2x you need double the pixels. So 29pt is 29 pixels for the 1x image and it needs to be 58 pixels for the 2x version. And now with 3x it would be 87 pixels.

Comment: How does that work with iPad Pro iOS 9-10 which has a 83.5pt requirement?

Comment: @user3690202 The iPad Pro is a 2x device so the 83.5 pt icon needs to be 167 pixels.